# Recycle Bin items shredding

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, windows-shell

I'd like to shred the recycle bin data, but I don't know which is the best approach, so it goes:
 -  In windows vista and 7 the files are renamed starting with $R and a bunch of random chars and also a file starting with $I and the same random chars is created, this file contains some info about the file, including it's name. The $Recycler.bin directory also contains a Desktop.ini, I don't know what it does.
 - In below vista the management of the recycled files is done using hidden INFO2 files, which do the association between random file name and real name.

Now, let's say I want to build an app that can run on both below and above vista systems, what common strategy would you use? My first lead woud be to navigate the namespace, get the absolute path to the Recycler directories ovewrite the data within the files and delete them manually from the Recycler directories. I also need to notify the shell afterwards.

What other approaches would you use?

*Correct me if I'm wrong in the above statements. 
sources: [Here](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,1159633,00.asp) and [here](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/what-is-info2-file-hidden-in-recycled-or-recycler-folder/)

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Why not just disable or empty the recycle bin, since your requirement will make it useless anyway?

Comment: I want to do it all in an app. It won't be useless! who said I won't use it anymore, it is the user's option to use the app to empty the files within the recycle bin or to do it the old way, but the app will provide shredding the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using IShellFolder interface?

```
LPITEMIDLIST    pidlRecycleBin    = NULL;
SHGetSpecialFolderLocation (m_hWnd, CSIDL_BITBUCKET, &pidlRecycleBin);
[...]
```

Comment: About that : SHGetSpecialFolderLocation is not supported and may be altered or unavailable in the future. Instead, use SHGetFolderLocation. (msdn), anyway, I get the idea, I've used the IshellFolder interface but it only gives me the name of the $R ... files, and if I delete them the $I ... files will remain in the recycled directory and I don't want that.

Comment: And let's say I use that, and change the $R to $I and delete all the files, but what about the below vista operating systems ? I have already presented this choice of deleting all the files.

Comment: Why don't you use different solutions for different versions of Windows?

Comment: Because I want to write as less code ass possible and because I want to simplify the solution

Comment: I mean if (version >= vista) [use new solution] else [use IShellFolder] interface? BTW, I'm sure any solution can be deprecated in next version of OS.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I was just wandering if someone has something better.

Comment: Look, there are many things in Windows which has different API for different version because it deprecates in every new version, in some cases you have to write different code for every new version of Windows. Why do you care about it so much ?

Comment: @Tutankhamen: +1. Why so people have fear, if any function is deprecated. Your solution is good and relevant.

Comment: Don't delete the $R files manually. Invoke the "delete" command on the item. That will clean up all the necessary bookkeeping (be it INFO2, $R, $I, or whatever).